# COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI slow performance with different strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have an sql query that is used to search for a name in two columns:

```
set statistics time on
select top 200 lsp.Id, sp.Id as SanPhamId, t.Title, sp.MaNhaSanXuat, lsp.NhaSanXuat_id, ISNULL(lsp.GiaSi, 0) AS GiaSi, ISNULL(lsp.GiaLe, 0) AS GiaLe, ISNULL(lsp.GiaThau, 0) AS GiaThau
    , ISNULL(lsp.GiaVangLai, 0) AS GiaVangLai, ISNULL(lsp.GiaLoai1, 0) AS GiaLoai1, ISNULL(lsp.GiaLoai2, 0) AS GiaLoai2, ISNULL(lsp.GiaLoai3, 0) AS GiaLoai3, ISNULL(lsp.GiaLoai4, 0) AS GiaLoai4, ISNULL(lsp.ChietKhau, 0) AS ChietKhau, ta.TermRecord_id
    , case when aut.DisplayAlias in(N'donvi/cay-x-met', 'donvi/tam-x-met', 'donvi/cuon-x-met') then cast(sp.SoLuongCoTheBan as nvarchar) + ' x '+ cast(sp.ChieuDaiCoTheBan as nvarchar)
    when aut.DisplayAlias = N'donvi/cay-x-met-cđ' then case sp.TinhTrang when 'TonKho' then cast(round(sp.ChieuDaiCoTheBan/sp.ChieuDaiNhap, 2) as nvarchar) else cast(sp.SoLuongCoTheBan as nvarchar) end
    else cast(sp.SoLuongCoTheBan as nvarchar) end as CotheBan
    , sp.TinhTrang, aut.DisplayAlias, autlh.DisplayAlias as LoaiHang
from
    Futurify_QLBH_KhoHang_LoaiSanPhamPartRecord lsp
    inner join Orchard_Taxonomies_TermContentItem ta on lsp.Id = ta.TermsPartRecord_id
    inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord pub on pub.ContentItemRecord_id = lsp.Id
    inner join Title_TitlePartRecord t on t.Id = pub.Id
    inner join Futurify_QLBH_KhoHang_SanPhamPartRecord sp on sp.LoaiSanPham_id = lsp.Id
    inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord spver on spver.ContentItemRecord_id = sp.Id
    inner join Orchard_Autoroute_AutoroutePartRecord aut on aut.ContentItemRecord_id = sp.DonVi_Id
    inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord termVer on termVer.Id = aut.Id
    inner join Orchard_Taxonomies_TermContentItem termlh on lsp.Id = termlh.TermsPartRecord_id
    inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord termlhver on termlh.TermRecord_id = termlhver.ContentItemRecord_id
    inner join Orchard_Autoroute_AutoroutePartRecord autlh on autlh.Id = termlhver.Id
where ta.Field IN ('DonVi', 'LoaiSong') AND termVer.Published = 1 and pub.Published = 1 and spver.Published = 1 and sp.TrangThaiSanPham = 'Active' and termlhver.Published = 1 and termlh.Field = 'LoaiHang'
    and (t.Title LIKE N'%tns%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI or sp.MaNhaSanXuat LIKE N'%tns%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI)
order by lsp.Id
set statistics time off
```

My problem is line (near the last line)

```
and (t.Title LIKE N'%tns%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI or sp.MaNhaSanXuat LIKE N'%tns%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI)
```

When I search for the string "tns", the performance is too slow : CPU time = 1515 ms,  elapsed time = 1530 ms.

But when I search for string "ton" : CPU time = 203 ms,  elapsed time = 204 ms.

Then I removed the second `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`

```
and (t.Title LIKE N'%tns%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI or sp.MaNhaSanXuat LIKE N'%tns%')
```

The performance when I search for string "tns" is improved : CPU time = 203 ms,  elapsed time = 205 ms.

And performance when I search for string "ton" is also improved : CPU time = 79 ms,  elapsed time = 138 ms.

What did `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` do ?

Why is the performance when I search for those strings so different?

It's lucky that column `sp.MaNhaSanXuat` doesn't use an accent so I can remove the second `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`, but if it uses an accent, what should I do to improve the performance ?

Comment: Do you clear `CACHE/BUFFERS` between query execution?

Comment: yes, I clear CACHE after remove the second `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`, performance is really improved, when I add `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` back, performance when I search for string "tns" is slow again (about 1500ms), but still fast when search for string "ton"

Comment: I tested again with clearing cache/buffer for each query execution. The results are the same as above. The excute time when searching for string "tns" is always too much longer than searching for string "ton" (1500ms vs 160ms , with using `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` on columns `t.Title` & `sp.MaNhaSanXuat`),  performance is improved when not using `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` on column `sp.MaNhaSanXuat` (240ms vs 90ms)

Comment: Compare the execution plans.  I suspect the plans are different because a more accurate row count estimate can be obtained when the `COLLATE` clause is not specified.  The row count estimate with the non-sargable `COLLATE` expression is probably significantly different.

Comment: Try to use binary collations to increase performance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use binary collations to increase performance:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Title_TitlePartRecord
    ADD Title2 AS UPPER(VarCol) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_Bin2 PERSISTED
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Futurify_QLBH_KhoHang_SanPhamPartRecord
    ADD MaNhaSanXuat2 AS UPPER(MaNhaSanXuat) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 PERSISTED
GO


DECLARE @mask NVARCHAR(100) = N'tns'

...
WHERE ta.Field IN ('DonVi', 'LoaiSong')
    AND termVer.Published = 1
    AND pub.Published = 1
    AND spver.Published = 1
    AND sp.TrangThaiSanPham = 'Active'
    AND termlhver.Published = 1
    AND termlh.Field = 'LoaiHang'
    AND (
            t.Title2 LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@mask) + N'%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_Bin2
        OR
            sp.MaNhaSanXuat LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@mask) + N'%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_Bin2
    )
...
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your column is defined (in your `CREATE TABLE` statement) to uses the collation that you need (that is `Latin1_General_CI_AI` in your case) and ensure, that you got indexes setup for your columns. Then remove the `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` parts from your query. That should be all that is needed here.

You query runs slow, because you either have no appropriate indexes declared, or the collation of your column is not the same as the explicit one you use in your query. Using a different collation than the one on the underlying column is always a red flag when it comes to performance, because it is likely to skip the index (partially or entirely) and therefore leads to bad performance. Check your execution plan for the specifics.